# Get the earliest date from a column (Python Pandas) after csv.reader

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date

I load some data from a CSV file with multiple columns. In my csv.reader I have an IF function. I am trying to get the earliest date from a specific column (Start Date).

I first load the data:

```
for row in csv.reader(open('myFile.csv')):
  if row[4] == '56886':
    key = row[4] #key = (row[4], row[33][:4], row[4])
    startDate = row[19]
```

When I print the column (startDate) I am getting this:

[image]

01) I tried using the below:

```
content = min(content)
print(content)
```

and I got this in terminal:

[image]

02) Then I tried changing my code:

```
for row in csv.reader(open('myFile.csv',
        parse_dates=['Start Date'], 
        usecols=['Start Date']))
  if row[4] == '56886':
    key = row[4] #key = (row[4], row[33][:4], row[4])
    startDate = row[19]
```

and I got an **invalid syntax** error.

03) I tried changing the line to:

```
pandas.read_csv('myFile.csv', parse_dates=['Start Date'], usecols=['Start Date'])
```

and I got the same error.

What is the best workaround? I have not found a solution so far.

Comment: Using pandas, you can convert one complete colum using `pd.to_datetime(df["Start Date"])`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
#dont filter all columns by usecols    
df = pd.read_csv('file', parse_dates=['Start Date', 'End Date']) #columns to datetimes

#filter output first by column ID and then get min and max
a = df.loc[ df['ID'] == 56886, 'Start Date'].min()


b = df.loc[ df['ID'] == 56886, 'End Date'].max()
```

Comment: min and max work correctly on dates but run slowly for large data sets

Answer (score 0):

An example using pandas to convert one single item:

```
pd.to_datetime("08/27/2017")
```

An example using pandas to convert one list of strings:

```
times = []
for i in range(30):
    times.append(str(i+1)+"/01/2016")
datetimes = pd.to_datetime(times)
min(datetimes )
```